# How to generate url path in new Router Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

What analog `deprecated-router` method  `generate` in new Router 3.0.0?
Early it can take something like this:

`this._router.generate(['Profile']).urlPath;`

How do it on new router?

Comment: What do you need to do?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I need to get concrete route path.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#createUrlTree-anchor

```ts
var urlTree = this._router.createUrlTree(['Profile']);
```

You can pass the result to

```ts
this._router.navigate(/*string|UrlTree);
```

or get the URL

```ts
var url = this._router.createUrlTree(['Profile']).toString();
```

**Edit**: As of Angular 6, you pass the result to NavigateByUrl:

```ts
this._router.navigateByUrl(string|UrlTree);
```

Comment: I thought, it create new route. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

These are the current examples from the page referenced by Günter

```
// create /team/33/user/11
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, 'user', 11]);

// create /team/33;expand=true/user/11
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, {expand: true}, 'user', 11]);

// you can collapse static segments like this (this works only with the first passed-in value):
router.createUrlTree(['/team/33/user', userId]);

// If the first segment can contain slashes, and you do not want the router to split it, you
// can do the following:

router.createUrlTree([{segmentPath: '/one/two'}]);

// create /team/33/(user/11//right:chat)
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, {outlets: {primary: 'user/11', right: 'chat'}}]);

// remove the right secondary node
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, {outlets: {primary: 'user/11', right: null}}]);

// assuming the current url is `/team/33/user/11` and the route points to `user/11`

// navigate to /team/33/user/11/details
router.createUrlTree(['details'], {relativeTo: route});

// navigate to /team/33/user/22
router.createUrlTree(['../22'], {relativeTo: route});

// navigate to /team/44/user/22
router.createUrlTree(['../../team/44/user/22'], {relativeTo: route});
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#createUrlTree-anchor